# How to import different policies inside OPA rego policy?

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent, rego, authzforce

I am working on writing new rego policies.

I have few rules defined in single policy file which I want to break into sub policy and import it.

Something like this:

A.rego

```
package com.example
import com.example.B.evaluate

default allow:= false
allow {
    evaluate
}
```

B.rego

```
package com.example

default evaluate:= false
evaluate {
    input.role != "admin" # some condition
}
```

How to achieve this policy configuration? It's like implementing policySet from authzforce having multiple sub-policies.

Thanks in advance!
Please pardon my knowledge of OPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bundle your policies they will all be combined into one large policy, so they will be segmented based on the package name, not the file name.

some_name.rego

```
package com.example.A
import com.example.B.evaluate

default allow := false
allow {
    evaluate
}
```

another_name.rego

```
package com.example.B

default evaluate := false
evaluate {
    input.role != "admin" # some condition
}
```

Also shown in our docs here, which I'll admit is a little light. So if there's anything we can add to make it more understandable just let me know!

https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#packages

Cheers,
@peteroneilljr
OPA Advocate