# How to import policies from different files

Tags: opa, rego

This could potentially be a duplicate of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73646952/how-to-import-different-policies-inside-opa-rego-policy) but I'm still having real trouble.

I have a function defined in one file.

A.rego

```
package authorizer

default username := null

decode_user(jwt) := user_id {
    // logic to decode token & return user_id
}
```

When I try and import it into another file, I get an error when I run `opa eval`.

B.rego

```
package user

import data.authorizer

default allow := false 

user_id := x {
    x := decode_user(input.jwt)
}

allow := true {
    user_id != null
}
```

Output of `opa eval`:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "undefined function decode_user",
      "code": "rego_type_error",
      "location": {
        "file": "",
        "row": 8,
        "col": 7
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I get the import to work? I have scenarios which effectively involve nesting policies and importing `golang` functions so understanding this is pretty important.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is this tagged "go"?

Answer (score 1):

Try either

```
import data.authorizer.decode_user
```

or if you want everything in that package

```
import data.authorizer.*
```